# Issue ordering columns by the first letter in blank columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my tables

```
|users|
  |id|   |lastname1|   |lastname2|   |name|   |company_name|
   1      Messi         Ramirez      Lionel      
   2      Gates         Bush         Bill        
   3      Klose         Kazer        Miroslav    
   4      Ozil          Demon        Mezut       
   5                                             Facebook
   6                                             GMAIL
   7                                             MYSPACE
   8                                             Twitter
```

I'm trying to order company_name like a lastname1.

Some friends gave me this [code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79964/1) but is not working with blank values just with NULL values:

```
select * from users 
order by COALESCE(lastname1,company_name),lastname2,name ASC;
```

I should have this answer

Note: the first letter of "facebook" is F and "Gates" is G so it continues with the next letter.

```
   5                                             Facebook
   2      Gates         Bush         Bill        
   6                                             GMAIL
   3      Klose         Kazer        Miroslav    
   1      Messi         Ramirez      Lionel      
   7                                             MYSPACE
   4      Ozil          Demon        Mezut       
   8                                             Twitter
```

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
order by coalesce(lastname1, company_name)
```

I'm not sure what the other columns are contributing to the `order by` so I removed them.

EDIT:

If the values are blank or spaces and not NULL, then use `case`:

```
order by (case when trim(lastname1) = '' or lastname1 is null then company_name
               else lastname1
          end)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me and also you should change "companyname" for company_name"

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with this query:

```
select * from users 
order by COALESCE(lastname1,company_name),lastname2,name ASC;
```

[COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) takes the first non null element of it's list.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54592/11)

If as in the modified question empty strings should be considered equally to NULL then you could do this with

```
select * from users 
order by 
CASE 
    WHEN TRIM(lastname1) = '' THEN company_name
    WHEN lastname1 IS NULL THEN company_name
    ELSE lastname1
END;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79964/11)

Comment: Ok great seems to be working with NULL values but is not working if is blank like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79964/1